# How to save content from a JTextField into a file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextfield, jtextarea

I am doing a project where i am inputting recipes and their corresponding info, (title, ingredients, utilities, directions) in a JFrame, and then i want to save that content to a file. The fields where the user inputs the data are(title,ingredients etc.) and they are JTextFields. What i need to know is how the text from that JTextField can be written to a new file. I would prefer that each field has its own file, so the title of the recipe alone would have its own file, e.g stirfry.txt, and then the content would be "stirfry"

Any feedback would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the content of your textfield using the getText() function
Create a new file using java.io
and write the content of the file using a BufferedStream.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use the `write()` method of JTextField.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

```
void saveToFile(String fileName, JTextField textField) throws Exception {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName, true);
   out.write(textField.getText().getBytes());
}
```

Comment: This is going to overwrite the content every time it's called

Comment: @MadProgrammer - updated the code to append to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
JTextField titleTextField = ...;
String title = titleTextField.getText();
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(title+".txt"));
fw.write(title);
fw.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The question depends on the format you want the file to take.

The text of the fields can retrieved by using `JTextField#getText`.  Take a look at [How to use text fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for more details...

If you simply have a key/name pair of values, for example, you could simply add each of the values from your text fields into a `Properties` object and utilise it's `save` functionality.  The has the added benefit of being able to load the file again via the `Properties` API.  Take a look at the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) tutorial for more details

This does, however assume, that each element is unique.

If you're after a more complex or flexible data structure you may need to use XML.  Luckily, Java has a bindings API which can allow you to transform an object to and from XML.  Take a look at [Introduction to JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) for more details.

The ultimate solution would be to use some kind of database ;)